# Accessing Struts2 Action - Not Correct Namespace

Tags: struts2

In struts.xml:

```
<package namespace="/" extends="struts-default" ...>
    <action name="home" ... >

    </action>
</package>
```

Accessing the action will be `/home`. What is it that the action can also be accessed in `/user/home`? How to restrict it?

Thanks

Comment: For the why - see http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/namespace-configuration.html. For the how - why do you want to restrict it?

Comment: Have you another namespace called "user" ? Post more details please

Comment: yes, there is namepsace `user` already